# error TS2339: Property 'startWith' does not exist on type 'Subject<string>'

Tags: angular

I am getting the below error in an Angular 7 project. I have installed the typescript using npm, which could mean the latest typescript version.

> error TS2339: Property 'startWith' does not exist on type 'Subject< string >'.

**app.component.ts**

```js
this.language
    .startWith(this.translationService.getBrowserLang())
    .subscribe(lang => this.store.dispatch(new LanguageAction(lang)))
```

**tsconfig.json**

```js
{
  "compileOnSave": false,
  "compilerOptions": {
    "baseUrl": "./",
    "outDir": "./dist/out-tsc",
    "sourceMap": true,
    "declaration": false,
    "module": "es2015",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "target": "es5",
    "typeRoots": [
      "node_modules/@types"
    ],
    "lib": [
      "es2018",
      "dom"
    ]
  }
}
```

**tsconfig.app.json**
[image]

Comment: you are trying to use a utility of string go through https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_startswith.asp

I guess you have to make logic in using `pipe`

Comment: https://www.learnrxjs.io/operators/combination/startwith.html

Comment: @Bibin Could you please also add the code of how you declare/initialize or inject `this.language`?

Answer (score 1):

you are trying to use in wrong way.
you have to use `pipe` as well on subject.

https://www.learnrxjs.io/operators/combination/startwith.html

Also when you are using a subject it is no more a string.
and you are trying to use utility of string.

Answer (score 1):

Like @The Mechanic already said, you are trying to use the `startWith` method directly on the `Subject`. Starting with version 5.5, the operators are [pipeable](https://github.com/ReactiveX/rxjs/blob/master/doc/pipeable-operators.md). If you want to filter out the correct values, use this instead:

```js
this.language.pipe(
  startWith(this.translationService.getBrowserLang())
).subscribe(lang => this.store.dispatch(new LanguageAction(lang)));
```